# Sending email to owner when the record is created

Tags: trigger

I have an object called Response_Documents_vgs__c . Requirement is, When this record is created, a mail should be sent to its owner means who created this record. I created an email template for this.

This is the html code of template

```
Dear {!Response_Documents_vgs__c.CreatedBy} <br/>

Your Response document is Created. You can download it from <a href="{!Response_Documents_vgs__c.Document_Location_vgs__c}"> here </a>
```

Now on after insert of response document, i am writing this code.

```
public static void sendEmail(List<Response_Documents_vgs__c> resps){
    List<EmailTemplate> template = [select Id,Name,Subject,body from EmailTemplate where name = 'EmailWhenResDocCreate'];
    List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage>();
    List<ID> targetObjectIds = new List<ID>();
    if( !template.isEmpty()){
        for(Response_Documents_vgs__c doc : resps){
            targetObjectIds.add(doc.createdById);

            Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
            mail.saveAsActivity = false;

            mail.setTargetObjectIds(targetObjectIds);
            mail.setTemplateId(template[0].Id);

            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            emailList.add(mail);

        }
        // Send the email
        Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
    }
}
```

sendEmail is the method that i am calling  from trigger with Trigger.new as parameter.

Now email is going to the user but it is

> "Dear
>
> Your Response document is Created. You can download it from here "

means it is not having name after "Dear" and "here" is the simple text not hyperlink. The only problem is i dont know  how to send the response document to  template.

Any help regarding this would be great.

Comment: You need to set the [WhatId](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm#apex_Messaging_MassEmailMessage_setWhatIds) so that the merge fields work correctly. If your trigger is on insert then the id will not be available.

Comment: But according to this doc, The whatId values must be one of the following types:

Contract
Case
Opportunity
Product. How can i do it for custom object?

Comment: I am used to using the [SingleEmailMessage](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) to send the emails, which allows the [WhatId](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId) to be a custom object. Is there any reason you are using MassEmailMessage?

Comment: When i am using SingleEmailMessage, i am getting this exception Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, sendEmailToOwner: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.: [] Class.sendEmailToOwnerLogic.sendEmail: line 20, column 1 Trigger.sendEmailToOwner: line 2, column 1: []

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a workflow for this?

Comment: @SachinKadian, can you please let me know if my answer is useful to you. My answer is a working version of your problem. I don't know why somebody has voted down.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the Email Template and the Trigger code. This sends an email when a record is created. Hope this will help.

Email Template - (Subjected - Record is created)

```
Dear {!CreatedBy} 
Your Response document is Created. You can download it from {!Document_Location_vgs__c}
```

Trigger Code

```
trigger SendEmail  on Response_Documents_vgs__c (after insert) {
    Response_Documents_vgs__c rdv= trigger.new[0]; 
    ID userid = rdv.CreatedById; 
    User activeUser = [SELECT Name,Email FROM User WHERE Id = :userid limit 1];
    String userName = activeUser.Name;
    String userEmail = activeUser.Email;
    String location = rdv.Document_Location_vgs__c;
    System.debug(rdv.Document_Location_vgs__c);
    System.debug(userEmail);
    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = '00Xi0000000Kbba']; //Email Template's ID
    String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!CreatedBy}', userName );
    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Document_Location_vgs__c}', location );
    String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;
    plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!CreatedBy}', userName );
    plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Document_Location_vgs__c}', location );

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support'); //Sender's Display name
    mail.setReplyTo('support@salesforce.com'); //Sender's Email ID
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mail.setSubject(emailTemplate.Subject);
    mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
    mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);
    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
    sendTo.add(userEmail);
    mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);       
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailmessage[] {mail});     
}
```

Email Received

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look into the page below.

http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/03/01/sending-emails-using-apex/